# My man page is empty

Tags: manpages

When I try to see man for socket I get an empty page.
What's going on?

I get the following text in man

```
Manual page socket(3) line ?/? (END)
```

It seems man can not identify line (maybe).

How can I make it work?

My socket file for manpages is also available:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3365 2010-05-03 09:30 /usr/share/man/man3/socket.3.gz
```

Comment: nope.  works on a fairly stock Ubuntu 10.04 install.  but different distributions include different manpages in different packages; not all get installed in a default system.  what Linux distribution and version are you using?

Comment: I use ubuntu 9.04.
It's not all the man page cannot be shown. some of it can but some of the others cannot.
<br>
when i type `man man` I can see the manual.<br>
but when i try `man socket`, I cannot see it.

<br>
do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think my manpages file is not supported by man-db 2.5.5.
After I install older man-db (2.4) I can see the manpages.

Confusing....

Comment: hmm.  sounds like something's broken in the formatting of that manpage that doesn't work with the newer package.  perhaps recompiling/regenerating the manpage from the source package would help, but keeping the older man-db package is probably the simpler solution.

Comment: a simpler fix, if this is the only manpage you're seeing a problem with, might be to grab that manpage from a later version of Ubuntu (9.10 or 10.04).  i wouldn't install the whole package; instead, extract just the one file to replace */usr/share/man/man3/socket.3.gz*

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your man settings? Do you have a valid MANPATH, or better: did not set MANPATH at all, so you can be sure, man finds the proper page?

Did you have a look in /usr/man/man3* or /usr/share/man/man3* (not sure, where it is on Ubuntu)? Is there a valid source file for the socket system call?

There is a chance that some other tool installed its own version of a socket man page, e.g. TCL; run man -a socket to see every man page related to socket or maybe better, run "man -k socket" or "apropos socket" to find all man pages that refer to sockets in any way.

Did you check your installation packages? Nothing damaged or missing?

Good luck,

Klaus

Comment: sure, i got this one.

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3365 2010-05-03 09:30 /usr/share/man/man3/socket.3.gz